# Weird Output for Printf Unsigned Long

Tags: c, printf, multiplication, 16-bit

This one is simple.

```
printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)(320 * 200));
```

That line of code prints out "4294965760". That is definitely NOT equal to 360 * 200. What's wrong with it?

I am using Digital Mars C compiler in 16 bit medium memory model.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce your result](http://ideone.com/5DEcfs)

Comment: You cast the *result* of '320 * 200' but that is 64000 and 64000 does not fit into a signed 16-bit integer (undefined behaviour). Try again without the parenthese around `320 * 200`. If it still fails: curse the compiler.

Comment: But an unsigned long is NOT a 16bit integer AND it's unsigned. It's a 4 byte int, which means 32 bits... so curse the compiler??

Comment: @SeanRamey but you don't use it, you use the 16-bit signed integer because of the parentheses aroiund '320'200'. Ah, someone was able to repeat that behaviour, so see Nazime Lakehal's answer. And: yes, curse the compiler, it should have warned you.

Comment: @SeanRamey: No — don't curse the compiler.  (Or, at least, the compiler is innocent.)  Your problem is that the multiplication is done before the conversion to `unsigned long`, and you're converting an overflowed 16-bit signed quantity to `unsigned long`, which is UB officially.  The bug is in your code; compilers are rarely at fault.  It does happen.  It does not happen often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a 16-bit system, if `sizeof(int) == 2`, then `320 * 200`, which is equal to `64000`, is too big for a signed `int` (range ±32,767 — and usually -32,768 too, but in theory it varies by platform).  So, you have arithmetic overflow.  The cast doesn't affect the multiplication; it only affects what happens to the result of the multiplication.

You'd do better with:

```
printf("%lu\n", 320UL * 200UL);
```

That forces the constants to `unsigned long`.

Comment: I don't understand? Isn't that what I have?? Where does everybody get "Signed Int" from?? I'm clearly type casting 320 * 200 to an unsigned long int which is 4 bytes, and using "%lu" which means to printf an unsigned long int.

Comment: THIS WORKS! But why? I don't get it? What's different about the constants and the type cast?

Comment: 320 is a (signed) `int` value.  200 is a (signed) `int` value.  When the compiler sees `320 * 200`, it has to multiply two (signed) `int` values, which yields a (signed and overflowed) `int` value.  Then, when it has done that, it has to convert the result (an overflowed (signed) `int` value) to `unsigned long`.  The overflowed value is negative; that translates to a big `unsigned long` value.  You could probably use `320U * 200U` since `64000` is smaller than `65535`, the maximum 16-bit `unsigned int`, and converting that to `unsigned long` would be clean too.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. I didn't know that constants could overflow! I thought that it really didn't matter what the constant was until I assigned it to a variable. So by default, all constant numbers are signed ints?

Comment: All small enough constants are signed `int`, yes.  If the constant is too big to fit in a signed `int`, then decimal constants are treated as `long` or `long long` (the smaller one that it will fit in).  Octal and hexadecimal constants can become `unsigned int`, or `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` too — again, depending on what the value fits in.  See section 6.4.4.1 Integer constants in the C standard for the details — there's a table there that defines what I've summarized here.

Comment: Incidentally, it was very important and very helpful that you said "Digital Mars C Compiler in 16-bit medium memory model" — that allowed me to deduce this answer for you.  Thanks for including that information.

Comment: Something not mentioned yet; the overflow is undefined behaviour

Answer (score -1):

I just tried this in my code and I got 64000. 
Maybe the problem is that `320*200` is a signed number! And when you cast it,  they have some problem with it at bits level? Try

```
unsigned long x = 320*200;
printf("%lu\n", x);
//64000 =                      0b1111101000000000
//4294965760 = 0b11111111111111111111101000000000
```

See that the first bits match! So it's probably problem of cast.